# Typeclass in haskell

Tags: string, haskell, typeclass

I'm extremely new to haskell and was trying to implement a small and a simple function that takes two strings and tells me the number of same characters at the same location.

```
ed :: (Integral b) => [a] -> [a] -> b
ed _ [] = 0
ed [] _ = 0
ed [] [] = 0
ed (x:xs) (y:ys)
    | x == y = 1 + ed xs ys
    | otherwise = ed xs ys
```

this doesn't run because my typeclass definition is wrong. I have two strings and need to return an integer and hence the typeclass definition I have written above. Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: Just a note: Now the third case, `ed [] []` is unnecessary, it's already covered by the first.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The type signature should be

```
ed :: (Eq a, Integral b) => [a] -> [a] -> b
```

This is because your definition of `ed` includes the expression `x == y`. `x` and `y` both have type `a`; to be able to test them for equality, this type must implement the `Eq` typeclass, which provides the `==` and `/=` operators.

The error message you got would have included something like this:

> ```
> Could not deduce (Eq a) arising from a use of `=='
> from the context (Integral b)
>   bound by the type signature for ed :: Integral b => [a] -> [a] -> b
>   at /home/dave/tmp/so.hs:(2,1)-(5,26)
> Possible fix:
>   add (Eq a) to the context of
>     the type signature for ed :: Integral b => [a] -> [a] -> b
> ```

which was trying to tell you this.

(Btw, your code doesn't handle the case when when the strings have different lengths.)

Comment: thanks a lot for that explanation. I wanted to understand exactly what does the expression in the parenthesis do. Then why even bother to include Integral b there? Wouldn't something like this suffice?ed :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Int                    

I looked up the net but most resources seemed to be talking about monads and stuff. Just wanted a simpler explanation. Also, yea, I corrected that different size thing as well...

Comment: @shashydhar `ed :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Int` would be fine too, only if you need to be able to have return values of different types (`Int`, `Integer`, `Word`, ...) would you need to be polymorphic in the result type.

Answer (score 4):

Because of the x == y, you need to add an Eq type constraint:

```
ed :: (Integral b, Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> b
```

You can comment out the type signature, load your module in ghci and let it figure out the type signature:

```
Main> :t ed
ed :: (Eq a1, Num a) => [a1] -> [a1] -> a
```